# How to access Alertmanager, Grafana and Prometheus URLs or DNS records with ingress in the kube_prometheus_stack helm chart values.yaml file?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager, haproxy-ingress

In the **kube_prometheus_stack helm chart** values.yaml file, I made the following changes to access the DNS records of **Alertmanager**, **Grafana** and **Prometheus** with ingress. Since we are currently using **haproxy ingress** for other services on EKS Kubernetes, I used haproxy ingress.

For Alertmanager:

```
alertmanager:
  enabled: true   
  serviceAccount:
    create: true
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    annotations:
      ingressClassName: haproxy
      cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt"
      haproxy.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
      haproxy.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: cert-manager    
    hosts:
      - alertmanager.monitoring.new.io       
    tls:
      - secretName: alertmanager-tls
        hosts:
          - alertmanager.monitoring.new.io      
  service:
    port: 443
    targetPort: 9093
```

For Grafana:

```
grafana:
  enabled: true
  service:
    port: 443
    targetPort: 3000
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    annotations:
      cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt"
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: haproxy
      haproxy.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
      haproxy.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: cert-manager
    hosts:
      - grafana.monitoring.new.io      
    tls: 
      - secretName: test-grafana-tls
        hosts:
        - grafana.monitoring.new.io
```

For Prometheus:

```
prometheus:
  enabled: true
  serviceAccount:
    create: true
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    annotations:
      ingressClassName: haproxy
      cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt"
      haproxy.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
      haproxy.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: cert-manager
    hosts:
      - prometheus.monitoring.new.io    
    tls:
      - secretName: prometheus-tls
        hosts:
          - prometheus.monitoring.new.io    
  service:
    port: 443
    targetPort: 9090
```

I also defined DNS records on **AWS Route-53** and made the necessary settings. But I can only access the **Grafana WEb interface** from the Grafana URL. When I try to access the **Alertmanager** and **Prometheus** web interfaces, I get a "**default backend - 404**" error.

Although I did a lot of research, I could not reach a clear conclusion. I wonder if I need to try a different method or where am I going wrong?